# Combine multiple rows into multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, case

Here's the data in table

| item_code | name_type | name_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | full | item 1 full name |
| 1 | short | item 1 short name |
| 1 | half | item 1 half name |
| 1 | semi | item 1 semi name |
| 2 | short | item 2 short name |
| 3 | half | item 3 half name |

I want the output as follows

| item_code | full_name | short_name | half_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 full name | item 1 short name | item 1 half name |
| 2 | - | item 2 short name | - |
| 3 | - | - | item 3 half name |

I used the case statement, but that didn't work.

```
select item_code,
    case name_type
      when 'full' then name_value
    end as full_name
    case name_type
      when 'short' then name_value
    end as short_name
    case name_type
      when 'half' then name_value
    end as half_name;
```

Comment: @AllanWind why max? they are all string values, right?

Comment: Try without and see what happens.  When you do group by, your select expr iterates over many rows and you usually tell which one you want with an aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need group by item_code to get a single row per group, then use an aggregate like max() to get the non-null value for each group:

```
select
    item_code,
    max(
      case name_type
        when 'full' then name_value
      end
    ) as full_name,
    max(
      case name_type
        when 'short' then name_value
      end
    ) as short_name,
    max(
      case name_type
        when 'half' then name_value
      end 
    ) as half_name
from t
group by 1;
```